# Command line arguments to Docker CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to pass in a parameter into a docker CMD. For example, if the contents of `Dockerfile` are

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cat", "$1"]
```

Then I want to run as follows:

```
docker build -t cat_a_file .
docker run -v `pwd`:/data cat_a_file /data/Dockerfile
```

I would like the contents of `Dockerfile` to be printed to the screen. But instead, Docker thinks that `/data/Dockerfile` is a script that should override the `CMD`, giving the error

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 7cfca4: 
[8] System error: exec: "/data/Dockerfile": permission denied
```

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `ENTRYPOINT` for stuff like this. Any `CMD` parameters are appended to the given `ENTRYPOINT`.

So, if you update the Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cat"]
```

Things should work as you wish.

Also, as you don't need the `$1`, you should be able to change it to:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/cat"]
```

I haven't tested any of this, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Just so we can make more complicated scripts, what is the correct way to use the `$1`-style argument?

Comment: Probably best to use environment variables in those cases. You can't use `$1` etc.